# Showing that these two groups are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have the following two groups ,

$G=\mathbb{Z}*_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}$, that is  free product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ amalgamated over $\mathbb{Z}$.

$H$ is the group which is given by the following presentation 
$$H=<a,b\;|\;abab^{-1}>$$

First of all I want to know whether these two groups are isomorphic or not. If yes, how should I prove it?

Comment: *How* is given the amalgamation?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I was calculating the fundamental group of Klein Bottle using Van-Kampen Theorem. I got this group $G$ as the fundamental group. But by using the other methods I got group $H$ as the fundamental group. May be I missed something.

Comment: "The free product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$  amalgamated with $\mathbb{Z}$" means nothing if you do not specify the morphisms. See the answer below. At any rate, your calculations are correct: the fundamental group of the Klein bottle is a (precisely defined) amalgamated product of this kind, and the morphisms are those prescribed by the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Since this question does not make any sense, Should I remove it ?

Comment: I did not say that the question does not make sense, but simply that you do not give enough information for a precise answer. However, I think it can be useful for someone else, I would leave it.

Comment: ok, Thanks for your input.

Comment: Go back to your van Kampen diagram. The amalgamation comes from identifying a generator of $\pi_1(U\cap V)$ with its images in both $\pi_1(U)$ and $\pi_1(V)$ What are those two images? Identifying them with each other should do it. The homomorphisms Francesco Polizzi want you to describe are those induced by inclusions $U\cap V\to U$ and $U\cap V\to V$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the question is currently written, there is not a unique answer to it.

The structure of $G*_{F}H$ depends on the two homomorphisms $\phi\colon F\rightarrow G$ and $\psi\colon F\rightarrow H$ given, as one has:
$$G*_FH=(G*F)/N,$$
where $N$ is the normal subgroup of $G*H$ generated by $\{\phi(f)\psi^{-1}f;f\in F\}$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}*_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}$ is ambiguous as they are infinitely homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.